# SQL insert from table A into table B based on condition from table C

Tags: sql, sql-server

table article has rows which are unique articles (columns: journalId, dataId, articleId)
table journal has rows which are unique journals (columns: journalId, ISSN)
table data has rows which are journal data (ISSN, dataId, ...)
(journal data is not in the journal table for an external reason)

ISSN is an alternate key in both the journal and data tables.

I would like to add a reference from article.dataId to data.dataId.
In order to do that I need to compare the article's journalId with the journal table, then get the article's ISSN and then compare that ISSN with the ISSN column in the data table to determine which dataId from data.dataId belongs in article.dataId

how do I do this? 
I can run basic queries in sql but I am struggling with this. Thanks.

Comment: What SQL have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Update statement with inner join can be used

```
 Update journalData 
 Set dataid = A.dataid
 From joirnalData JD
 Inner join journal J
 On JD.ISSN = J.ISSN
 Inner join article A 
 On A.journalid = J.journalid
```